# Splitting Android Layout Vertically Adding Gravity To Both Sides To Center Objects

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

I have an android layout I'd like to split down the middle vertically and then add gravity so I can center items within the left and the right halves of the layout.

Can someone explain or post an example of how this might be accomplished?

Thus far I've created a layout and a horizontal layout. My problem is the horizontal layout needs balance so I'd like to figure out a way to change my current layout (show below) to include a way of centering the objects within the left and right halves of the screen.

SOURCE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/emblem"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:scaleType="fitStart"
         android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/go_button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emblem"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
         android:background="@drawable/apn_app_go_button" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/go_button"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/start_text2"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just got 2 downvotes - why is this a terrible question? I'll repost/edit it if someone can explain what I've done wrong.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe you could upload image of what you wana achive. What are those "items"?

Comment: pls put some of your code what you have done , and also a screen shot of what do you want. If you don't show what you have coded or tried to code , then you will get downvotes.

Comment: I just did : ) (thanks for the tip!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `android:orientation` attribute will not work in `Relative Layout`.If you want to split the screen half into two equal layout your parent layout will be a `linear layout` with `android:orientation= horizontal`. Then inside that have 2 `LinearLayout` with each `android:orientation= vertical`. Inside 1st `Linear layout` you can have  the `ImageView` , `Button` and `TextView` with each of their `layout_gravity=center`.

Hope this helps. If you want to do something in the 2nd half of teh screen , do all teh stuffs in the 2nd LinearLayout.
Happy Coding.

Comment: Nailed it... implemented it - it's working! Thank you! (Should I post what I did for future users?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code which should be self-explanotory:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#00dd00"
        android:gravity="center"
     >

      <Button 
          android:text="Button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#dd0000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

        <Button 
          android:text="Button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's what you'll achieve:

[image]